# Dynamically added event handlers doesn't work as expected in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have written event handlers for a `PictureBox` that is created with my MainForm
The pictureBox is named `pictureBoxBackGround`.
I add dynamically more pictureBoxes and associate their event handlers to the event handlers of `pictureBoxBackGround`, because i want the to act the same way.
The event handlers work fine when i move the `pictureBoxBackGround`, but they doesnt work properly with the new pictureBoxes.

Here are the event handlers:

```
 private void pictureBoxBackGround_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //Begin Move 

        m_pointLastMousePos = Cursor.Position;

        m_bIsPictureBeingMoved = true;
    }

    private void pictureBoxBackGround_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //End Move
        m_bIsPictureBeingMoved = false;
    }

    private void pictureBoxBackGround_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(m_bIsPictureBeingMoved == true)
        {
            PictureBox picboxSelected = sender as PictureBox;

            int nHorizontalChange = Cursor.Position.X - m_pointLastMousePos.X;

            int nVerticalChange   = Cursor.Position.Y - m_pointLastMousePos.Y;

            Point pointNewImagePosition = pictureBoxBackGround.Location;

            pointNewImagePosition.X = pointNewImagePosition.X + nHorizontalChange;

            pointNewImagePosition.Y = pointNewImagePosition.Y + nVerticalChange;

            if (pointNewImagePosition.X > 0 &&
                pointNewImagePosition.Y > 0)
            {
                picboxSelected.Location = pointNewImagePosition;

                m_pointLastMousePos = Cursor.Position;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how i attach them:

```
picBox.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBoxBackGround_MouseDown);

            picBox.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBoxBackGround_MouseUp);

            picBox.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBoxBackGround_MouseMove);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're still using the original picturebox inside the event, for instance this line:

```
Point pointNewImagePosition = pictureBoxBackGround.Location;
```

You need to ensure all references to a picturebox inside the events go to the `sender`, and not to `pictureBoxBackGround`. So this line should be:

```
Point pointNewImagePosition = picboxSelected.Location;
```